# How to detect whether current major-mode allows dashes ("-") in its symbol names?

Tags: syntax, coding-conventions

To enable [smart-dash](http://malsyned.net/smart-dash.html) ("an Emacs minor mode which redefines the dash key to insert an underscore within C-style identifiers and a dash otherwise") after falling in love with Kebab/Lisp case,

I want to check whether current programming language supports Kebab case and activate `smart-dash` when it doesn't.

Approaches tried:

- Exhaustively call `(add-hook <mode-hook> #'smart-dash-mode)` for every known non-Kebab case language.
- Find current `major-mode`'s syntax, so far I have not found a uniform way, for Common Lisp it's a variable: `lisp-mode-symbol-regexp`, for Python it's `(python-rx (syntax symbol))`
- Utilize [smartparens](https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens):

```lisp
(defun smart-dash-maybe (&rest _)
  (when (require 'smartparens)
    (unless (member major-mode (append '(
                                         sh-mode ;commands with "-" are common
                                         cobol-mode forth-mode css-mode ;According to Wikipedia
                                         )
                                       sp-lisp-modes))
      (smart-dash-mode))))
```

But it requires an external package.

Comment: `(char-syntax ?-)` (although I have no idea what 'Kebab' case is)

Comment: @rpluim But how to know if it belongs to "symbols" class? Is `(string= "_" (string (char-syntax ?-)))` correct?

Comment: Yes, although you can use `char-equal` rather than converting to a string